# How to separe these values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to do this around 2 hours and my brain is about to explode.
I have a table called `DEPARTMENTS` and a column called `TOTAL_ROOMS` but each `DEPARTAMENT` have their own room size but I don't know how to show the total rooms of each department.

It should look something like this

```
DEPARTMENT NAME ||  TOTAL DEPARTMENTS || TOTAL DEPARTMENTS WITH ONE ROOM || TOTAL DEPARTMENTS WITH TWO ROOMS || TOTAL DEPARTMENTS WITH THREE ROOMS

EXAMPLE A       ||          10        ||          5                      ||           3                      ||             2

EXAMPLE B       ||           8        ||          2                      ||           4                      ||             2
```

I Have tried using a `WHERE` , `IN`, `DISTINCT` function but I'm not very professional doing this (I'm still learning) :/ This is what I've done and the column name about rooms size is `TOTAL_ROOMS` and I'm trying to `SUM` every `ROOM` that has "1 room size" then `SUM` every `ROOM` that has "2 room size" and shows the result :/

```
SELECT TOWER.EDI_NAME_TOWER AS "DEPARTMENT NAME",
COUNT(DEPARTAMENT.NRO_DEPARTAMENT) AS "TOTAL DEPARTMENTS"
FROM DEPARTAMENT
JOIN TOWER 
ON DEPARTAMENT.ID_TOWER= TOWER.ID_TOWER
GROUP BY TOWER.EDI_NAME_TOWER;
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the original data from `DEPARTMENT` and `TOWER` as well as the expected output you want to get? Ideally in the format of a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: What data inside `NRO_DEPARTMENT` column? Room size?

Comment: Please explain how you know how many rooms there are for *any* department.  Why are you calling the "tower" name the name of the department?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what your data looks like so here's a guess where conditional aggregation (sum(case when...)) is used to separate the columns.

```
drop table if exists t,t1;

create table t (ID_TOWER int,NRO_DEPARTAMENT int);
create table t1(id_tower int, EDI_NAME_TOWER varchar(3));

insert into t values
(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,3),(1,3),
(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,2),(2,2),(2,3),(2,3),(2,3),(2,3);

insert into t1 values
(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb');

SELECT TOWER.EDI_NAME_TOWER AS "DEPARTMENT NAME",
        count(DEPARTAMENT.NRO_DEPARTAMENT) AS "TOTAL DEPARTMENTS",
        sum(case when DEPARTAMENT.NRO_DEPARTAMENT = 1 then 1 else 0 end) '1 room',
        sum(case when DEPARTAMENT.NRO_DEPARTAMENT = 2 then 1 else 0 end) '2 room',
        sum(case when DEPARTAMENT.NRO_DEPARTAMENT = 3 then 1 else 0 end) '3 room'
FROM t DEPARTAMENT
JOIN t1 TOWER 
ON DEPARTAMENT.ID_TOWER= TOWER.ID_TOWER
GROUP BY TOWER.EDI_NAME_TOWER;

+-----------------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| DEPARTMENT NAME | TOTAL DEPARTMENTS | 1 room | 2 room | 3 room |
+-----------------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| aaa             |                10 |      5 |      3 |      2 |
| bbb             |                10 |      4 |      2 |      4 |
+-----------------+-------------------+--------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If this is not what your data looks like please add sample data as text to the question. If you have more rooms keep adding aggregations, if that becomes unmanageable consider dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers and sorry for the delay.
@P.Salmon you gave me an idea but i tried and i even failed… This is what i need to show

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMPtL.png)

this is my code

```
SELECT EDIFICIO.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO AS "NOMBRE EDIFICIO", 
COUNT(DEPARTAMENTO.NRO_DEPARTAMENTO) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS",
SUM(TOTAL_DORMITORIOS) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO", -- fix
COUNT(TOTAL_DORMITORIOS) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 2 DORMITORIO", -- fix
COUNT(TOTAL_DORMITORIOS) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 3 DORMITORIO", -- fix
COUNT(TOTAL_DORMITORIOS) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 4 DORMITORIO", -- fix
COUNT(TOTAL_DORMITORIOS) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 5 DORMITORIO" -- fix
FROM DEPARTAMENTO
JOIN EDIFICIO ON DEPARTAMENTO.ID_EDIFICIO= EDIFICIO.ID_EDIFICIO
GROUP BY EDIFICIO.EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO
ORDER BY EDI_NOMBRE_EDIFICIO;
```

I'm pretty sure it can be done using SUM ! and i was trying this but i don't know how to sum every value and show the result final per department

```
SELECT ID_EDIFICIO, NRO_DEPARTAMENTO, TOTAL_DORMITORIOS
FROM DEPARTAMENTO
WHERE TOTAL_DORMITORIOS IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

EDIT ---- THANKS P.Salmon i just figured out the code

```
SUM(CASE WHEN TOTAL_DORMITORIOS = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "TOTAL DEPTOS 1 DORMITORIO",
```

This sum every room per department!